# glTranslatef not moving with z axis

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I write app which draw a rectangle on screen. I want to move this rectangle on z axis but it isn't working. It disappears. I don`t know how to repair that.

Code:

```
package game;


import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        glfwInit();
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        long  window = glfwCreateWindow(1280   ,720,"Title",0,0);

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        GL.createCapabilities();

        ///////////////////////////////
        glTranslatef(0,0,5);
        ///////////////////////////////


        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
            glfwPollEvents();
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex2f(-0.5f,0.5f);
                glVertex2f(-0.5f,-0.5f);
                glVertex2f(0.5f,-0.5f);
                glVertex2f(0.5f,0.5f);
            glEnd();
            System.out.println(z);
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
        System.exit(0 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, only things inside the cube with x,y,z coordinates from -1 to 1 are shown. Because of the `glTranslatef` at the beginning of your code, you're effectively rendering a square at the coordinates

`(-0.5f,0.5f,5), (-0.5f,-0.5f,5), (0.5f,-0.5f,5), (0.5f,0.5f,5)`

This lies outside of the cube, therefore it isn't shown.

To change the coordinates in which things are rendered, I recommend looking into `glOrtho` and `glFrustum`. With `glFrustum` you'll also be able to see things in perspective 3D.

Comment: but how shoud i set glFrustum to see perspective ?

Comment: [Here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations) is a huge wiki article on how exactly to go about looking at things properly using legacy OpenGL.

Comment: After 3 hours finally i do this! THANK YOU